# GoDaddy and .htaccess 301 redirects in subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, errordocument

My website points to a sub-sub folder on the webroot on GoDaddy (/mywebsite/mywebsitesfolder). Apparently from my research, you cannot use a 301 redirect in an .htaccess file if it's in a subfolder of the webroot on GoDaddy. I've tried so many different things. My custom ErrorDocument statements work and bring up the error documents within this particular subfolder, of which my domain points to. What should I do to make this work aside from moving my website completely out of GoDaddy and to Bluehost?

```
rewriteengine on 

redirect 301 /oldfile.html http://mynewsite/newfile.php

ErrorDocument 404 /.errordocs/404-missing.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here but it works like this. In order to successfully do a 301 redirect for domains pointing to subfolders on GoDaddy, you have to put the complete file path where you want the server to LOOK for the old file. I was getting confused because my old site was in a different folder and I was telling it to look in that old folder instead of the new folder I pointed the domain to. So my code would actually look like this instead of what's above in my question.

```
redirect 301 /mywebsitesfolder/oldfile.html http://www.newsite.com/newfile.html
```

No matter how many subfolders down in the webroot it is, you have to put the whole filepath. Im my case, my redirects now look like this:

```
redirect 301 /mywebsitesfolder/mywebsitesnewfolder/oldfile.html http://www.newsite.com/newfile.html
```